# Are cloud functions that trigger from authentication events guaranteed to run?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

E.g. if I have

`functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => { ... creates some docs in firestore db }`

is this guaranteed to always run when a user is created? Does the trigger wait for an ACK from the cloud function guaranteeing that it has ran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are cloud functions that trigger from authentication events guaranteed
> to run?

Yes, as explained in the Cloud Functions [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries), for asynchronous background functions (i.e. non-HTTPS Cloud Functions, like Cloud Functions triggered by Authentication events), Cloud Functions "guarantees at-least-once execution of an event-driven function for each event emitted by an event source".

---

Note that "*at-least-once execution*" means that Cloud Functions does not guarantee that it will be executed **only** once: in some rare cases the platform may run it more that once, see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE) for more details.